# How to get the value of an enum being passed to the JNI

Tags: java, enums, java-native-interface

I have a Java application and JNI (dll). I want to know how to get the value of the enum (int) that is being passed as a parameter to the JNI.

Here's the enum (Java):

```
public enum envelopeType
{
    NOT_SPECIFIED(-1),
    NONE(0),
    IMAGE(1),
    BITMAP(2);

    private int value;

    private envelopeType(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}
```

Here's the JNI code (C++):

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Loader_Convert
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject EnvelopeType)
```

since the enum is being passed as an object, how could I get the value of that?

Answer (score 7):

I was not able to use the solution provided by @tbodt but his was close enough that I was able to find the solution.

Looking at the [java enum documentaiton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) there is the method `ordinal` that will return the enum value as an `int` type.

The code I used was almost identical to that lised in @tbodts solution however the strings passed into the `GetMethodID` function are different. I don't need to create a `getValue` method and the method signature is `()I` not `I()`.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Loader_Convert(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject EnvelopeType) {
    jmethodID envelopeGetValueMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/of/envelopeType"), "ordinal", "()I");
    jint value = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, EnvelopeType, envelopeGetValueMethod);
    switch (value) {
        case -1:
        // not specified
        break;
        case 0:
        // none
        break;
        ...
    }
    // rest of native method
}
```

Comment: That's the real answer, since it doesn't require to modify the enum.

Comment: Thanks, though I will probably just pass the ordinal() value to the JNI function that accepts an int. Seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 3):

You would provide a method to return the value of `value`, then call that from the native code and use a `switch` statement. Here's the method in the enum:

```
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

And your native method:

```c
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Loader_Convert(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject EnvelopeType) {
    jmethodID envelopeGetValueMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "package/of/envelopeType"), "getValue", "()I");
    jint value = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, EnvelopeType, envelopeGetValueMethod);
    switch (value) {
        case -1:
        // not specified
        break;
        case 0:
        // none
        break;
        ...
    }
    // rest of native method
}
```

Comment: I will in just a minute, after I learn about JNI. (Just kidding, I know a little bit about it.)

Comment: Actually, there is no need to add a method. The native function can just as well `GetFieldID()` for the _private_ field "value", and use `GetIntField()` to analyze the value with the same switch logic.

Comment: I didn't native methods could access private fields without anything like `setAccessible(true)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've tried the code you provided above but jvm crashes when calling CallIntMethod. 

Here's the code: 

jclass envelopeTypeClass = env->FindClass("JacsLoader");
jmethodID EnvelopeGetValueMethod = env->GetMethodID(envelopeTypeClass, "getValue", "I()");
jint envelopeTypeValue = env->CallIntMethod(EnvelopeType, inputEnvelopeGetValueMethod);

Comment: @BebzSusuma Any exception? That could happen because of a misspelling in a method name or signature.

Comment: How could I catch the exception in JNI?

Comment: well, first what is the exception

Comment: jvm only shows these:  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5ac59d7b, pid=2908, tid=6868
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa9d7b]

Comment: OK, then I have no idea what is going on, especially given I know practically nothing about native methods.

Comment: You must provide the full "path" to class to FindClass function. Luckily,  you don't need this at all: use GetObjectClass() instead.

Comment: I try to put some exception handling in my JNI. something like this: 

    jclass inputEnvelopeClass = env->GetObjectClass(inputEnvelope);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) 
    { MessageBox(NULL,"exception here","",0); }

The message box is being displayed meaning there's really an exception. What's wrong with GetObjectClass()?

Comment: You have a syntax typo. Change : "I()" to -> "()I". the first argument represent what the function get and the second what it return. ()-> i don't take argument. I -> return int

Answer (score 3):

Actually, instead of defining `getValue()` method you can call `Enum.ordinal()`.

A simpler solution is to modify slightly your C code and use `Enum.ordinal()` directly when calling the JNI function, i.e. to pass a `jint` instead the `Enum` object:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Loader_convert
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint EnvelopeType)
```

And in Java you got a sort of

```
loader.convert(myEnvelopeType.ordinal());
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29